# What is the difference between FeatureCollection (GEE made vs. loaded asset) in GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to run an analysis over a FeatureCollection. It works perfectly, if I create the collection in GEE:

```
var p1 = ee.Geometry.Point([-122.64550158728298,38.44643840127136]);
var p2 = ee.Geometry.Point([-123.06960473413164,38.54089331487732]);
var p3 = ee.Geometry.Point([-122.85149523962673,38.33988067525676]);
var asset_points = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List([ee.Feature(p1),ee.Feature(p2),ee.Feature(p3)]));
```

However, if I load a shapefile from my asset it fails:

```
var asset_points = ee.FeatureCollection("users/slisovski/AssetPoints");
```

The problem is making a Feature in [L76:80](https://code.earthengine.google.com/cab4e4dda87b6814857282409e77c078):

```
ee.Feature(geom, {date:   image.date(),
                  name:   featname,
                  fitted: valF,
                  orig:   valO});
```

With the error: Error in map(ID=2_0): String: Parameter 'input' is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When such an error occurs in a mapping function, make sure to get that feature/image with the error, and apply the similar code *without* the mapping. Then you can print your variables within the mapping function and analyse where the error came from.

```
var testImage = mm.filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:index', '2_1')).first();
print('testImage',testImage)
```

You would then have seen that in that image, your key `Original` was *null*. That gives an error, because an ee.String cannot have null as input. An useful workaround is apply `combine()` on the dictionary output with an empty dictionary. The function `combine()` removes null values from a dictionary.

```
var valueF = testImage.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.median(), geom, 30)
    // remove null values using 'combine'. 
    // Combine a dictionary with an empty dictionary, and null values are removed
    .combine(ee.Dictionary()) // make line green to see error
print('1', valueF)
```

Now you will be able to apply the mapping. [See link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/6e951de19fa93a8ec853690acfe6c21e)